# What is the difference between Closure::new and Closure::wrap in Rust wasm

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

What is the difference between [Closure::new](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/closure/struct.Closure.html#method.new) and [Closure::wrap](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/closure/struct.Closure.html#method.wrap)?

Both are used to create closure but I wanna know when to use these functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple, all that `Closure::new` does is put the closure in a `Box` , unsize it and delegate to `wrap` as you can see by looking at the [code](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/src/wasm_bindgen/closure.rs.html#271-276):

> ```rust
>     pub fn new<F>(t: F) -> Closure<T>
>     where
>         F: IntoWasmClosure<T> + 'static,
>     {
>         Closure::wrap(Box::new(t).unsize())
>     }
> ```

So use `Closure::new` when you have a bare Rust closure or function and use `wrap` when your closure is already a trait object contained in a `Box` (`Box<dyn Fn>` or `Box<dyn FnMut>`) as `new` would wrap it in an additional `Box` and thus create unnecessary indirection.